# Custom Painter class not visible in Stack flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas

For some reason, the `Stack` widget does not show the `Container` with the `CustomPaint`.

However if removed from `Stack`, it works fine. What am I missing here?

```
class _DemoNavBar extends State<DemoNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
        home:
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(child: CustomPaint(painter: CurvePainter()))
      ],
    )
    );
  }
}

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.green[800];
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height - 100); 

    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height - 100); 
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7, size.height, size.width * 0.9,
        size.height - 100); 
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 100); 
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height); 
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking the source of `CustomPaint` it says

```
  /// The size that this [CustomPaint] should aim for, given the layout
  /// constraints, if there is no child.
  ///
  /// Defaults to [Size.zero].
  ///
  /// If there's a child, this is ignored, and the size of the child is used
  /// instead.
```

So, give it a size. Other solutions include 1) providing width and height to the parent `Container` of `CustomPaint` and 2) provide a child for the `CustomPaint` which will ignore the `size` provided in the solution below.

---

I checked this code to work fine.
`size: MediaQuery.of(context).size` uses the complete screen size.

```
void main() {
  runApp(SO());
}

class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DemoNavBar(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoNavBar createState() => _DemoNavBar();
}

class _DemoNavBar extends State<DemoNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomPaint(
          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
          painter: CurvePainter(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.green[800];
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height - 100);

    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height - 100);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7, size.height, size.width * 0.9, size.height - 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

---

Now, the reason is since `Container` has no parent or child to provide the size it takes complete screen size and works fine without `Stack`. When a stack is used size goes to zero which is given to the custom painter.

Equivalent code can be written as

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: CurvePainter(),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

the end result is

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How does it work without a size when removing it from the Stack then?

Comment: if you give width and height to the container inside the stack then those width and height will be used by custompaint.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: ```No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget```

Comment: Yes, I know the reason; it is already fixed in the code. There needs to be a MaterialApp higher in the tree. I suggest you paste the code exactly as answered the check the result if it works for you. Comment the rest of your code and use the code in answer.

Comment: I wish this was mentioned in the class documentation in the website.

Comment: @WilsonSilva It is mentioned in the docs. Check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint/size.html and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html. But better explained in the source code.

Comment: @Doc Thanks. Good catch. I was expecting it to be documented in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html.